# Changes to an IEnumerable are not being kept between queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

`IEnumerable` is a query that is lazily evaluated. But apparently my understanding is a bit flawed. I'd expect the following to work:

```
        // e.Result is JSON from a server
        JObject data = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        // LINQ query to transform the JSON into Story objects
        var stories = data["nodes"].Select(
                   obj => obj["node"]).Select(
                        storyData => storyOfJson(serializer, storyData));

        // set a value on each story returned by the query
        foreach (Story story in stories)
        {
            story.Vid = vid;
        }

        // run through the query again, making sure the value was actually set
        foreach (Story story in stories)
        {
            // FAILS - story.VID is 0
            Debug.Assert(story.Vid == vid);
        }
```

What am I misunderstanding here? How can I alter the results of what this query returns?

Comment: Hi, what's the error?  Where is vid initialized?

Comment: An `IEnumerable<T>` is just a sequence of items (such as an array).  LINQ methods, and other iterator methods, return an `IEnumerable<T>` implementation that is lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each time you enumerate the `stories` variable, the `Select` call runs again, creating a new set of `Story` objects.

Therefore, each `foreach` loop runs on a different set of `Story` instances.

You need to force the LINQ calls to evaluate exactly once by calling `.ToArray()`.
Looping through the resulting array will not re-evaluate the LINQ calls (since it's a normal array), so you'll share the same set of `Story` instances.

Comment: Note that using any collection type would be fine (i.e. ToList()). +1.

Comment: The select does not run until the first time stories is enumerated, but select does not run again on the second enumeration.

Comment: @Dennis: Wrong.  It will run again every time you use a new enumerator.  (The results aren't cached anywhere)

Comment: then I learned something new. I will have to write some test cases. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `IEnumerable` in this case contains the return values of `storyOfJson` called repeatedly on the collection, not the original values.

When you enumerate the collection inside the `foreach`, the function is repeatedly called as necessary, and the result of the function call is placed into the `foreach` iteration variable (`story` in this case).

If you want to store the set of `Story` objects, you'll have to put them into some form of collection first, because the enumerated items are destroyed once the loop terminates.

Side Note: You should probably use the LINQ syntax rather than the functional syntax when possible.

```
var stories = data["nodes"].Select(obj => obj["node"]).Select(storyData => storyOfJson(serializer, storyData));
```

becomes

```
var stories = from node in data["nodes"]
              select storyOfJson(serializer, node["node"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the LINQ syntax. I wasn't sure how to make it work, but that's much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable` is supposed to be treated like a read-only collection.  While some programs might return an existing collection, rather than a copy, other programs are free to return a new copy each time.  For example, when you add `.Select(storyData => storyOfJson(...))`, you will get new objects each time.

This means that if you edit the copy you get, then perform the query/call get again, then your changes will be wiped out.

If you want to edit the results of the query, either add your own `.Select()` on top of the resulting query, to perform the transformation you are interested in, ala:

```
var filteredStoried = stories.Select(s => new Story(s) { Vid = vid });

foreach(var s in filteredStories)
    Assert(s.Vid == vid);
```

Or copy the query results to a local collection, and work with that:

```
var localStories = new List<Story>(stories);

foreach(var s in localStories)
    s.Vid = vid;

foreach(var s in localStories)
    Assert(s.Vid == vid);
```

Comment: Wouldn't adding that `Select` on top be a waste of speed?

Comment: @Rosarch: It creates new objects each time.  Whether this is a waste or not is up to the overall program architecture.  If someone edits the collection, then it won't effect your class's local instance.  This makes it easier to write a bug-free program.  If, later, you determine it to be a performance bottleneck (via profiling), you can always alter it to return the same instance each time.

Comment: @Rosarch: Btw, the `ToList()` answer is basically the same as the 2nd answer I've given you here.  The syntax for `ToList()` is better, of course.  Both will create a new `List<Story>` object, which allocates extra storage to hold all the references.